# Python rarfile package: BadRarFile

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, rar

I need to parse .rar files in Python, so I tried rarfile module. It works fine, when I open it, rf.infolist() works properly, etc.

However, when I try to read corresponding files in the rar-file, I get the **rarfile.BadRarFile: Failed the read enough data** error. I cannot figure the source of the problem. System - macOS Mojave

Example code:

```
    with rarfile.RarFile(archive) as rf:
        json_data = [f for f in rf.infolist() if f.filename.endswith('apartment_data.json')][0]
        with rf.open(json_data.filename, 'r') as f:
            # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the rarfile!

I met the same situation today!

Use the following code:

```
import patoolib
patoolib.extract_archive(archive_file, outdir='')
```

It can also be used to uncompress the rar file.